# Toggle line number display in nano on a Mac

Tags: command-line, nano, usability

Is there a keyboard shortcut for toggling line number display in the nano editor on a Mac? The keyboard shortcut`Option-#` that works in Linux work doesn't work on a Mac. I read where someone suggested `Control-#` or `Control-C` but they don't work either.

I realize it can be set in the nanorc configuration file, but I only want to see line numbers when I need them, like when I need to see which line an error is occurring on, hence the desire to toggle the display.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>esc</kbd><kbd>n</kbd> and <kbd>esc</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>#</kbd> work on macOS.

> Meta-key sequences are notated with 'M-' and can be entered
> using either the Alt, Cmd, or Esc key, depending on your keyboard setup.

Comment: esc-n works. Thanks!

Comment: I have on #macos "GNU nano version 2.0.6 (compiled 02:20:53, Aug 29 2022)" and not work even with command line arg `nano: unrecognized option '--linenumbers'`

Comment: Make sure you have the brew version of nano first in your path. The current version of GNU nano is 6.4. The one in /usr/bin/nano is a symlink to pico. Apple silicon macs have a slightly different install path for brew.
`which -a nano`
`/usr/local/bin/nano`
`/usr/bin/nano`
`/usr/local/bin/nano --version`
`GNU nano, version 6.4`
`/usr/bin/nano@ -> pico`